# Handling and Parsing ASP.NET Web service with AFNetworking in ios

Tags: ios, afnetworking

When I parse the `ASP.NET` Web service with `AFNetworking` in my code it shows some error but I unable to fix these error.

Here I give the error and my code.

The Error is...

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x175caf70> { URL: http://52.88.103.214/Trotoise_Exported1/Trotoiseweb/Monument.asmx/GetMonumentListByRange } { status code: 500, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Content-Type";
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = private;
"Content-Length" = 313;
"Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 26 Oct 2016 07:52:12 GMT";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://ipaddress/places/Monument.asmx/GetMonument, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<53797374 656d2e49 6e76616c 69644f70 65726174 696f6e45 78636570 74696f6e 3a204d69 7373696e 67207061 72616
```

Here I give my code what I am tried...

```
NSArray *responses = [json objectForKey:@"responses"];
    NSLog(@"%@", responses);

    locactionDict = [[responses valueForKey:@"landmarkAnnotations"]valueForKey:@"locations"];
    NSLog(@"Latitude and Longitude is: %@", locactionDict);

    latStr = [[locactionDict valueForKey:@"latLng"]valueForKey:@"latitude"];
    NSLog(@"Latitude is: %@", latStr);
    longStr = [[locactionDict valueForKey:@"latLng"]valueForKey:@"longitude"];
    NSLog(@"Longitude is: %@", longStr);

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"lat":latStr,@"lng":longStr,@"rad":@"5",@"lang":@"en"};

    [manager POST:@"http://ipaddress/places/Monument.asmx/GetMonument" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON is %@",jsonObject);
    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

              NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          }];
```

Comment: You are getting 500 from the server, which means:

Internal Error 500
"The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."

It seems the bug is on the server side, not on the client side

Comment: But it will worked and implemented in android.

Comment: It will worked outside the App, it mean i will implemented this in sample task but not worked in app.

Comment: it is in back end issue

Comment: If I hard coded(statically) the parameters it will worked. but give dynamically not worked.

Comment: Try using https://www.charlesproxy.com and compare the differences between your failing request and a working request. Its has a 30 day free trial so you don't have to pay for it right away :)